# Tantulum cap issues: Xray die construction misalignment & dirty marking

Tags: capacitor

I'm having some tantalum polymer capacitor die misalignment and physical dirty marking problem. I hope that I can get any advice from someone; whether this can impact the functionality of the component? Can this be acceptable? How can it happen? [image]

[image]

Comment: Can you not measure C? It does not look good for supplier QA process control

Comment: Hi Stewart, Capacitance is okay. But I check with supplier they mentioned that dark mark on the units on corners and in middle then this was alwasy there just the size has some variation. This is related to cutting of molding gates by the laser. So it is related to sed technology and it is normal.

Comment: no idea whether is true or not ? and the die misalignment also one of my concern which I haven't check with MFG

Comment: Anyone seen this two case before? Any advise? will it affected functionality? the Die shouldn't look like this right?

Comment: Hi Tony, What do you mean not measure C?